# Google BigQuery - invalid table name - PHP

Tags: php, google-bigquery

I'm testing out access to my BigQuery table (currently has 3 rows in it, per the dashboard). My code is:

```
    $google_project_id = <my_project_id>;
    $google_dataset_id = 'photo_proecssing';
    $google_table_id   = 'stats';

    $table_name = "{$google_project_id}.{$google_dataset_id}.{$google_table_id}";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `$table_name` LIMIT 1000";

    // Initialize GoogleCloudStorage access
    $google_client_config = [
        'projectId'   => <my_project_id>
        'keyFilePath' => <path to my key file>
    ];

    $google_client = new Google_Client( $google_client_config );
    $google_big_query_service = new Google_Service_Bigquery($google_client);

    // setting up auth stuff for the client
    $google_client->setAuthConfig( <path to my key file> );
    $google_client->setScopes( [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery' ] );

    $jobs = $google_big_query_service->jobs;
    $query = new Google_Service_Bigquery_QueryRequest();
    $query->setQuery( $sql );

    $response = $jobs->query($google_project_id, $query);
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
    message:  Invalid table name: `<my project id>.photo_processing.stats`
```

I copied the exact query from the dashboard query panel, using the same tablename, where it works fine.

Note: I also tried a delete query (which is really what I want to do):

```
DELETE FROM `trans-radius-764.photo_processing.stats` WHERE created_date < '2022-05-25 15-15-07'
```

And it throws an error "Unrecognized token DELETE".

Any ideas?

Comment: Check if your are using **starndardSQL** first.  **legacySQL** will generate **Unrecognized token** error for **DELETE**.

Comment: Can you share how you installed `Google_Service_Bigquery` and then how you imported it in your code?